# Creating a simple video gallery

Tags: php, video

I am using php and i want to create a video gallery.
THe videos as i know would be uploaded to an external source...
However i am confused about how to implement this...
For example if the user put a video from youtube ,ok i can write code to limit its width/height
But if itsnt from utube what can i do ??
I am confused . Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the width and height of the video you can use the console tool `ffmpeg`.

There are a lot of questions related to this tool here at SO and in the internet.